# Better to stay in the open or in the water during an earthquake?

Tags: waves, water, earthquake

I tried looking around on google but couldn't really find any good information.

For arguments sake, say I am in a field with a river intersecting it. If an earthquake occurs and I am near the riverside, is it better to stay in the field or would the water provide more dampening from the earthquake? Assume the river has a gradual slope from 0-15 feet depth and is 100 feet wide.

Comment: You might want to ask this at [SE.EarthScience](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) instead.  The issue's that earthquakes are complex enough that subject-expertise would seem appropriate.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to protect yourself from? The shaking from an earthquake in itself presents very little hazard to people. The danger really comes from collapsing structures or land forms.

Comment: as charles says. The river , if a dam broke upstream due to the quake would be more dangerous, imo, than a rock rolling down from the hill  ( they stop after a few meters, so stay away from high structures, natural or man made)